# Disable leaflet interaction temporary

Tags: leaflet

How can I temporary disable zoming/draging the Mapview in Leaflet.js
Tried so many ways but without any luck.
It's important to make it temporary and I also need the option to enable again.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this with CSS? I need to disable dragging on mobile using a media query. I tried setting a transparent layer on top of it but it clicks right through that layer. I even played with pointer-events but no luck. The proper approach is most likely through the use of -webkit-user-drag: none; but I have applied that to every element I can find and still no luck. Thanks.

Comment: I answered this question [below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/288670/123137).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

your going to want to do (assuming your map is call `map`)

```
map.dragging.disable();
map.touchZoom.disable();
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
map.boxZoom.disable();
map.keyboard.disable();
if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();
document.getElementById('map').style.cursor='default';
```

turn it on again with

```
map.dragging.enable();
map.touchZoom.enable();
map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
map.boxZoom.enable();
map.keyboard.enable();
if (map.tap) map.tap.enable();
document.getElementById('map').style.cursor='grab';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking so wrong _ thought there must be a single method to do that.

Comment: This solution has some issues: The mouse cursor is still a hand. Page scrolling with touch gestures is not possible over the map. When the opening of a Popover moves the map it will never pan back.

Comment: @netAction, Do you have a solution to the touch gesture scrolling issue?

Comment: @ChrisFremgen: map.dragging.disable(); does the trick that the map stops fetching scrolling gestures.

Comment: Is there a way to only disable zoomIn?

Comment: Neither of these answers worked to stop clicks to the map from within the info div. I ended up creating a variable, changing its value on mouseover and mouseout, and checking against this variable in my map.on('click', ...) function before proceeding with the rest of the function.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to disable each handler manually, you can loop over all of them and disable/enable them.

Disable

```
map._handlers.forEach(function(handler) {
    handler.disable();

});
```

Enable

```
map._handlers.forEach(function(handler) {
    handler.enable();

});
```

Comment: Beware that using non public properties (_handlers) may cause error in your code even on leaflet patch version changes as it is not guaranteed to remain unchanged. Feature request should be submitted to leaflet ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think, you can wrap your map with a helper container and you can disable it with simple CSS class like `is-locked`.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```css
.map-container {
  position: relative;
}

.map-container .map {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.map-container.is-locked:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-leaflet with quite a few custom event handlers added to my leaflet map. I can't just stop propagation on the leaflet domevent because doing so caused issues (esp. with components from other frameworks I'm using such as material-ui).

So in case anybody is in the same boat, here's a solution that's working for me!

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { DomEvent } from 'leaflet'
import { useLeaflet } from 'react-leaflet'

const PreventLeafletControl = (props) => {
  const controlRef = useRef()
  const leaflet = useLeaflet()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (controlRef) {
      const eventsClone = leaflet.map._events
      const eventsEmpty = Object.keys(eventsClone).reduce((accumulator, key) =>
        accumulator[key] = []
      , {})
      DomEvent.addListener(controlRef.current, 'mouseover', () => {
        leaflet.map._events = eventsEmpty
        leaflet.map._handlers.forEach(handler => handler.disable())
      })
      DomEvent.addListener(controlRef.current, 'mouseout', () => {
        leaflet.map._handlers.forEach(handler => handler.enable())
        leaflet.map._events = eventsClone
      })
    }
  })

  return <div ref={controlRef}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
}

export default PreventLeafletControl
```

Just wrap `<PreventLeafletControl>` around your custom UI component and you should be good.

Comment: Please avoid duplicate answers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/376252/8104. More details here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/641151