# Leaflet map altering page scroll behavior

Tags: leaflet, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

When scrolling down a page and past a leaflet map, if the user's mouse cursor is inside of the map, then the scroll bar stops and the browser window becomes stuck on the map.

Is there a way to completely disable the scroll behavior on the map so that scrolling operates as normal?

I'm already using `map.dragging.disable();`

Comment: See here. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54454/disable-leaflet-interaction-temporary. Sounds like scrollWheelZoom is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this Plugin](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.Sleep) if you don't want to completely disable the scrolling function in the map. It allows to disable any map interaction until the user clicks on the map.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i achieve it using jQuery :

```
$('#mymap').on('load', function () {
    this.map.options.tap = !L.Browser.mobile;
    this.map.options.dragging = !L.Browser.mobile;
});
```