# Disable double click zoom event in Leaflet for R

Tags: r, leaflet, zoom, shiny

Is there a way to disable the double click zoom in Leaflet for R?

I've created a Shiny app that changes polygon styles when a country's region is clicked on/off. If you select and immediately deselect the same polygon, the map zooms in. I want to disable this feature so that there's no wonky zooming!

According to [leaflet.js documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomoptions), you can disable this feature in JavaScript. Leaflet for R refers to this documentation when I try to search for the solution within R, which is completely unhelpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the option `doubleClickZoom = FALSE` :

```
leaflet(data,options = leafletOptions(doubleClickZoom= FALSE)) %>% ...
```

Other options can be found here : [Disable leaflet interaction temporary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54454/disable-leaflet-interaction-temporary)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find an option to disable the **double click zoom** in the R `leaflet` package. So I tried to disable this option by passing `JavaScript` code as strings to the `shiny` web app.

You can try the reproducible example below.

```
library(leaflet)

#  Make Leaflet map with JavaScript

# // Leaflet providers
leafletProviders <- "var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                                                maxZoom: 19
                                                });"
# // Map definition
map <- "var map = L.map('map', {
                  center: [-34.7247, -56.1237],
                  zoom: 8,
                  layers: [OpenStreetMap_Mapnik]
                  });"

# // Basemaps
baseMaps <- "var baseMaps = {'OpenStreetMap': OpenStreetMap_Mapnik};"

# // Add a layer control element to the map
layerControl <- "layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, null, {
                                position: 'topleft'});
                                layerControl.addTo(map);"

ui <- fluidPage(

  leafletOutput("map"),
  HTML(paste("<script>", "\n", leafletProviders, "\n", map, "\n", baseMaps, "\n", layerControl,"\n", "</script>", sep = "")), # Make map JS code 
  HTML("<div id='divHtml' class='shiny-html-output'></div>") # Create empty div with known ID
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$divHtml <- renderUI({

    interaction <- "map.doubleClickZoom.disable();" # Modify interaction with map
    mapHtml <- HTML(paste("<script>", interaction, "</script>", sep = "")) # Put JS code for interaction with created map in created DIV element

    return(mapHtml)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: example]